# How to execute remote validation when button is clicked?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

I am using remote validation with data annotations to check is the username entered by the user already exists in the database.  My code looks like this:

```
[Required]
[Display(Name = "User name")]
[System.Web.Mvc.Remote("DoesUserNameExist", "Validation", ErrorMessage = "User name already exists, please select a different user name.")]
public override string UserName { get; set; }
```

By default, when you tab out or leave focus of the HTML version of this field, an ajax call is made to check the username.  However, I would like to only make the check when the user clicks on a button.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think it's pretty hard, because unobtrusive validation use jquery validation plugin, which have a remote method http://jqueryvalidation.org/remote-method, and it doesn't have parameter to set field validation event, i recommend you to use some trick:

set your submit button to plain button:

```
<input type="button" id="your-submit-button" value="send" />
```

or

```
<button type="button" id="your-submit-button">
</button>


$("#your-submit-button").click(function(event)
{
     event.preventDefault();
     if($("#form").valid())
     {
        $.ajax(
           //set option to ajax request validation
           success:function(valid){
                 if(valid){
                    //if ok send data
                    $('#form).submit();
                 }
           }
        )
     }
     return false;
})
```

Also i have my old server side code, maybe it also help you:

```
  public class AjaxValidatorController : Controller
{
    //
    // GET: /AjaxValidator/

    public JsonResult ValidateEmail(string email)
    {
        //
        var ValidatorEmail = new UserExistAttribute();
        bool ResultEmail = ValidatorEmail.IsValid(email);
        return Json(ResultEmail, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}

 public class IsUserExistAttribute : ValidationAttribute
{
    public override bool IsValid(object value)
    {
        if (Membership.FindUsersByEmail(Convert.ToString(value)).Count == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
}

public class RecoveryModel
{
    [IsUserExist(ErrorMessage="some message" )] 
    ...
    public string Email { get; set; }
    .....
}
```

In a future if have some difficult validtaion i recommend use directly http://jqueryvalidation.org/

Comment: Thanks for this.  I really gives me a direction to go.  Too bad the Remote attribute does not provide some kind of client side event processing that could be used.

Answer (score -1):

> I would like to only make the check when the user clicks on a button.
>   Is this possible?

Yes it is possible. You need to disable Client side validation for a particular view -

```
@{
    HtmlHelper.ClientValidationEnabled = false;
}
```

If you want to globally disable validation then you can disable it in the web.config -

```
<configuration>
    <appSettings>
        <add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="false"/>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="false"/>
    </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

**And one more important point here -** 
Unfortunately Remote Validation doesn't support server side validation. To get Server Side Validation, you can use this [Nuget from Tugberk Ugurlu](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/asp-net-mvc-server-side-remote-validation) and perform Remote Server side validation.